# Is this a CUSUM limitation?

Tags: structural-change

I'm using CUSUM to check structural breaks. The plot you see below pass the **CUSUM test**. How is that possible?

```
> cs <- sctest(pair.res ~ 1)
> cs

    Recursive CUSUM test

data:  pair.res ~ 1 
S = 0.9448, p-value = 0.05118
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is due to the presence of auto-correlation and possibly (probably!) untreated variance changes and perhaps even parameter changes over time.

Comment: ok, but why CUSUM doesn't detect the structural break, it is very clear.

Comment: Since my statements about the series are apparently true the variance is inflated thus it downward biases the CUSUM test to conclude that the null hypothesis of "no breaks" is then falsely accepted or at least not rejectable leading to the conclusion that nothing can be proved . Restated the alternative hypothesis of breaks can not be accepted.

Comment: @Dail, look at the assumptions of CUSUM test. IrishStat summarized the violations of these assumptions.